# AWS ALB in front of one server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer, aws-auto-scaling

I have a server (apache/php) running the front end of saas platform.
This will not receive high traffic and therefore does not need load balancing.

Does it make sense to add load balancer and auto scaling group (with count of 1 server) for security reasons?
It allows the server to be isolated in the VPC + it allow services such as WAF that increase security. The extra cost is not a problem.

Comment: In general, no -- there is no immediate benefit to using Auto Scaling and/or a Load Balancer. However, I like the points that @Anss makes.

Answer (score 4):

It does make sense in the following ways,

1. It can help you in configuring health checks for your instance. If
   you instance fails for some reasons, the load balancer will
   instantiate another EC2 instance for you hence minimizing the
   downtime of your application
2. Naturally makes your instance more secure by hiding it in a VPC (as you suggested)
3. Lastly, it will future-proof your architecture and will enable you
   to quickly scale up your infrastructure if need be

Answer (score 0):

As you said you have a single server and do not get much traffic add a load balancer to your server.

You can enable health checks so that by integrating it with SNS you will get notified if a health check fails( server unhealthy)

By adding WAF to your application load balancer you can monitor HTTP/S requests and control access to web applications.

It depends upon your requirement like with WAF you can

Block or allow traffic to your application  from a specific region

Block or allow traffic to your application from a specified IP range

You can mention the specific number of requests to your application within 5 minutes if it exceeds you can block or count.